# Google cloud functions sample error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to learn how to use Cloud Functions, I take this example from github: [Example here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/convert-images/functions/index.js) I just copied the code, But I have this error, what I am doing wrong? there is other examples to do this?:

```
!  functions[imageToJPG]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp-promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Comment: FYI you have a missing link in your question.

Comment: Sorry here is te correct link: [Correct link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/convert-images/functions/index.js)

Comment: You can edit the question to correct the link.

Comment: Sorry, I Just did it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change any of the code at all in the sample, it's almost certain that you didn't run `npm install` from the functions directory.

Comment: when I run `npm install` I have this message, is this a problem? `npm WARN firebase-functions@1.0.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.12.0 but none was installed.`

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: but how a fix that? :(

Comment: Try `npm install --save firebase-admin` as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)